# Error: Refused to get unsafe header "Location" in "tus-js-client" npm package

Tags: reactjs, tus

I'm using this(https://www.npmjs.com/package/tus-js-client) npm package to upload files in my react.js project and for most of the devices it's working fine but in some devices it's showing this(Refused to get unsafe header "Location") error in upload.js file of this package. I don't know how to fix it. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was happening because of old version of Chrome. I updated the Chrome in few devices and it started working.